# How to limit the object type and return the key of the object

Tags: typescript

i can use `keyof typeof`  to get object's keys, for example

```
const config = {
    a: {
        type: '123',
        age: 123,
    }
}

type IKeys = keyof typeof config; // 'a'
```

when i want to limit config type，for Example

```
type IItem = {
}

type IConfig = {
    [key: string]: {
       type: string;
       age: number;

    };
}

const config: IConfig = {
    a: {
        type: '123',
        age: 123,
    }
}

// oh~~
type keys = keyof typeof config; // 'string' | 'number'
```

how can i do to get original keys type `'a'`  and  limit config value with `IConfig`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to narrow `config` type to the most narrow possible type while constraining it to `extends IConfig`.

Here is how you could do it:

```
interface IConfig {
    [key: string]: {
        type: string;
        age: number;
    };
}

const narrow = <T extends IConfig>(conf: T) => conf;

const wrongConfig = {
    a: {
        type: '123',
        age: '123',
    }
}

const rightConfig = {
    a: {
        type: '123',
        age: 123,
    }
}

narrow(wrongConfig); // Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
const config = narrow(rightConfig); // Success: types are compatible, config is still typed as the most narrow possible type

type Keys = keyof typeof config; // "a"
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=27&ssc=40&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGED2IbAObIDeAsAFDIXIDaA1hAJ4BcyAzmFKHgLrMnmUCw9AA4RmbDiDwBuMgIFw8Y5CACuAWwBG0WfwoBfXfrJkE2NirhQomAO7IAvMgA8AFWQQAHpBAATFmhYOPgAfAAUZjjMrgCUjiHIkTC6puZgyLY2UkG4BE58Crxy8hRCoswA5ACMAEwAzBUANMUlisrV9U0tyMakvakgFhx4ABZgOfiORN1wRXryZe21Dc3zCkrMy6sCvf2kIFY2tmGZ2HgTeDHSyAD0N8gAotaYUNEiKBUSnBXIwAEgmHScBYLHwB00ABsUGBMMhFsgKmotNAKgMLElJk4Ds9jsMxhcrrd7gBlVQIJAg5iLAJWFBmdTCOBgYCQiCNRLYXK-AJsYAQiFw96%20ZDAuEjFDqTAWbFHZDCKWg1mC0QmUjwgDSDACTjo9EwMGVEH1HOCMiJyAARHALUA)